# How link two Python Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybuilder

Warning: Python newbie.

I have two `Python` projects A and B.

A depends on B.

I'm using `PyBuilder` to build both projects and I am struggling to link B into A.

My thoughts are I somehow need to install project B via `pip` or some-other method in the same way I would install `pandas`.

Then in A, declare B as a module dependency and I can then import it.

Does this make sense in the world of `Python`?  I have a setup.py for each project but they prob need some changes or `PyBuilder` needs to be told that module B is located in XYZ private git repo.  When I run `pyb --debug` I can see all dependencies are looked for in a location where by module is not present.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Is there any need to build the projects seperately? If not, simply import B into A and make A a module. Furthermore: On which platform are you?

Comment: Most probably you can locally install module B using your `setup.py` file with `python setup.py install` and then use that to import it into A.

Comment: @Dschoni yes this is why I believe is the approach, its just getting that to work nicely

Comment: Mac, but will be deployed on ubuntu within a Docker container.

Comment: Can you expand a little, why you want to build the projects at all? Is there a need for the inclusion of unit tests? Complicated compiling of header files? Dependency handling?

Comment: So A is a module of quant/math functions, and B is really just an i.o gateway containing Kafka or whatever.  I want the quant lib to be just that, a re-usable library just like pandas and for B to say I depend on A and treat it like it in the same way it would handle any other 3rd party python module.

Comment: That sounds as in your use case building of A is a little over-the-top for what you want to achieve. Just keep the python file of A at some location and import it whenever you need it. If you distribute B, bundle up A with it and build them together as one module or package (mind the difference). However. If you want to keep things tidy and modular (and e.g. want to distribute A without B), build and install A and introduce the dependency in B. Handle that inside pybuilder or distutils etc.

Comment: Ok got this figured out as I initially wanted - having two projects but one depending on the other.  I used pybuilder to make the setup.py files and docker to for deployment which make life very simple (in the end).

Comment: @Dschoni So to answer the earlier question. Yes pybuilder for structure, unit testing, dependencies, distribution zip and auto setup.py creation.  I didn't to bundle them up bec I wanted separate Git repos for the core and others for IO such as Kafka or REST.  Keeps the projects smaller and focused. In the end Docker makes this very achievable due to the nature of Python modules being installed.